# Infinite scroll is firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have looked for other answers on the same topic but still cannot find a solution why the event is firing more times in my code:

```
  (function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
    Drupal.behaviors.news = {
        'attach': function(context) {

            $(".loader").hide();
            var loadIndex = 0;
            var isLoading = false;

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if (!isLoading) {
                    var footerHight = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $("#myFooter").height();
                    if($(window).scrollTop() > footerHight){

                        isLoading = true;
                        loadIndex = loadIndex + 1;

                        $(".loader").show();
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: '/load-news?startIndex=' + loadIndex,
                            success: function (result) {
                                console.log("More loaded");
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    $(".loader").hide();
                                    onSuccess(result);
                                    isLoading = false;
                                }, 1000);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    };

    var onSuccess = function(data) {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
        $(".news-list-wrapper").append(data);
    };

})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `Drupal.behaviors` you need to use `.once('behaviorName')`

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

needs to be:

```
$(window, context).once('news').scroll(function(){
```